# Formik no limpia los campos despues de enviar los datos

Tags: next.js, formik

Tengo un componente de Next.js que es un formulario, tiene mas de 400 lineas asi que voy a intentar explicar lo que me pasa con poquito codigo, si hace falta algo mas me dicen y lo agrego.

```
const initialValues = {
    name: "",
    amount: "",
    cardNumber: "",
    expMonth: "",
    expYear: "",
    cvc: "",
  };


const [s4FormData, setS4FormData] = useState(initialValues);

<Formik
        validateOnChange
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        {({
          handleSubmit,
          handleChange,
          values,
          errors,
        }) => (
          <form
            className="booking-form"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
            <div className="inputs">
              <TextField
                FormHelperTextProps={{
                  className: "helper-text",
                }}
                className="name-input"

                // defaultValue=""
                error={Boolean(errors?.name)}
                helperText={errors?.name}
                label="Name"
                name="name"
                value={values?.name}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
```

El formulario funciona como corresponde, pero una vez que se envian los datos y se ejecuta este useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (paymentResponse && paymentResponse.succeed) {
      setS4FormData(initialValues);
      setS4NewCharge(null);
      setCardToken(null);
      setSendData(false);
    }
  }, [paymentResponse]);
```

Mi estado `s4FormData` vuelve al estado inicial pero los inputs de mi formulario no se limpian. Intenté alternando entre `value` y `defaultValue` sin éxito.

Alguien sabe que me está pasando?

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo solucioné "atandolo con alambre", estoy seguro que no es la forma óptima pero luego de buscar en un montón de lugares y probar multiples soluciones sin éxito, lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

- Creé una referencia para luego asignar a un botón:

  ```
   const clearBtnRef = useRef(null);
  ```
- Dentro del componente Formik agrego la prop `handleReset`

  ```
     <Formik
       validateOnChange
       initialValues={initialValues}
       validationSchema={validationSchema}
       onSubmit={onSubmit}
     >
       {({
         handleSubmit,
         handleChange,
         handleReset,
         errors,
         values,
       }) => (
       ...
  ```
- Luego dentro de mi formulario, al final del mismo agrego un boton que al clickearse ejecuta la funcion `handleReset`, con estilos que lo ocultan y le asigno la referencia creada previamente:

  ```
           <button
             ref={clearBtnRef}
             style={{
               opacity: 0,
               position: "absolute",
             }}
             onClick={handleReset}
           />
  ```
- Finalmente en el useEffect donde detecto que el formulario fue correctamente enviado, simulo un click en el boton oculto

  ```
  clearBtnRef.current.click();
  ```

Sé que no es una solución optima pero me sirvió para salir del paso. Si alguien tiene la solucion que corresponde a Formik le agredeceria mucho.